# C# net core simplifying Lambda expression cleverly - updated

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-core, autofac, masstransit

I am looking for a clever solution to simplify a Lambda expression which is growing longer and longer. It looks something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host("xyz", "/", hst =>
    {
        hst.Username("user");
        hst.Password("pass");
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_1", e =>
    {
        e.LoadFrom(provider);
        EndpointConvention.Map<Class1>(e.InputAddress);
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_2", e =>
    {
        e.LoadFrom(provider);
        EndpointConvention.Map<Class2>(e.InputAddress);
    });

    // ... a lot more of these here ....

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_n", e =>
    {
        e.LoadFrom(provider);
        EndpointConvention.Map<ClassN>(e.InputAddress);
    });
}));
```

This is part of a simple web api project, but the issue here isn't how services are setup, nor how the API endpoints work. It's just this piece of code getting verbose and redundant, something I wish I could avoid.

Maybe it's something simple, how could I generalize it and just pass a list of endpoint strings with the relevant class names without this big chunk of code?

Thanks - I tried researching this, but didn't find anything useful for this particular situation.

**Update 1**

After valuable suggestions from all of you, the code is rewritten in many ways. I have the following helper:

```
void ConfigureEndPoint<T>(IRabbitMqHost host, ref IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator cfg, IServiceProvider provider, string endPointName)
    where T:class
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endPointName, e =>
    {
        e.LoadFrom(provider);
        EndpointConvention.Map<T>(e.InputAddress);
    });
}
```

Then, the `Startup.cs` has certain annoying parts, which are also quite redundant, but necessarily easily rewritable, such as:

```
services.AddScoped<MyConsumer1>();
services.AddScoped<MyConsumer2>();
// a lot of them here
services.AddScoped<MyConsumerN>();
```

Why is it not simple? Each consumer inherits `MassTransit.IConsumer<T>`, but here T is either a command or a query, from which commands inherit a type of interface, and queries a completely different type of interface. Hence, I am really not sure how this can be made generic? Perhaps splitting it into 2 parts, 1 part for commands, 1 part for queries?

I also don't know how the `e.LoadFrom` could be correctly changed to `e.Consumer<SomeConsumer>(provider);` because the way I have setup the services isn't by default compatible with that call.

The consumers are also added to MassTransit after being added with `.AddScoped` as such:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<MyConsumer1>();
    // the rest of the consumers all here, all added the same way                
});
```

Then, again, from the initial question, the `CreateUsingRabbitMq` is a bit nicer, but still has N lines of:

```
ConfigureEndPoint<SomeCommandOrQuery>(host, ref cfg, provider, "endpoint_name_here");
```

I am sure there is a nice workaround to make the code shorter, more readable, but what are your ideas, how could I do it? How could I also replace `e.LoadFrom` with `e.Consume<SomeConsumer>()`?

Thank you, really appreciate the community and your ideas!

**UPDATE 2**

[image: Error message on using <code>services.AddMassTransit(provider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq()</code>]

I'm not sure what I am missing - my consumers all implement `IConsumer<T>`, which comes from the MassTransit namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood the concept of endpoints, consumers and conventions.

I am very concerned that you use `LoadFrom` for each endpoint. It means that *all* your consumers that are registered in the container will be listening in each endpoint.

Usually, if you want to split consumers per endpoint, you need to configure the endpoint explicitly by calling `ep.Consumer<MyConsumer>(provider)`.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_2", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<SomeConsumer>(provider);
});
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_2", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<SomeOtherConsumer>(provider);
});
```

When you use `LoadFrom`, each of your endpoints will have *all* consumers from the container. If you use `LoadFrom` for each endpoint, each endpoint will be subscribed to all your messages and you will get each message as many times as the number of such endpoints. Definitely, that is not what you want.

You probably misunderstood the meaning of `EndpointConventions`. The conventions are only used to send messages, not to receive messages. Endpoints will receive all messages that it can consume.

**Solution 1**

If you don't expect a lot of traffic, you might put all consumers in a single endpoint and then you can use `LoadFrom`.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "my_service", e =>
{
    e.LoadFrom(provider);
});
```

**Solution 2:**

If you want to separate consumers with one consumer per endpoint and use something similar to one-line endpoint configuration, it can be easily done by using this code:

```
using System;
using MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport;

namespace MassTransit.TestCode
{
    public static class BusConfigurationExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureEndpoint<T>(this IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator cfg,
            IRabbitMqHost host, string endpointName, IServiceProvider provider)
        where T : class, IConsumer
            => cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endpointName, ep => ep.Consumer<T>(provider));
    }
}
```

You then can use it like:

```
cfg.ConfigureEndpoint<SubmitOrderConsumer>(host, "submit_order", provider);
cfg.ConfigureEndpoint<MarkOrderAsPaidConsumer>(host, "mark_paid", provider);
cfg.ConfigureEndpoint<ShipOrderConsumer>(host, "ship_order", provider);
```

When using this extension, you *must not* use `AddMassTransit` method of the `MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, but you need to register all your consumer *dependencies* in the service collection.

However, I don't really see the point of having such an extension if you can still use this one-liner in the bus configuration code.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endpointName, ep => ep.Consumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>(provider));
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endpointName, ep => ep.Consumer<MarkOrderAsPaidConsumer>(provider));
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endpointName, ep => ep.Consumer<ShipOrderConsumer>(provider));
```

The fact that in my first snippet I used method groups doesn't imply that you cannot just use an expression lambda.

There will be a new package `MassTransit.AspNetCore` to integrate MassTransit with ASP.NET Core better, in the next release. It will configure the bus hosting, register the bus instance properly and also apply logging. The configuration will then look like this (this code works, I just wrote and tested it):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMassTransit(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "message_one", ep => ep.Consumer<MessageOneConsumer>(provider));
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "message_two", ep => ep.Consumer<MessageTwoConsumer>(provider));
    }));
}
```

Remember that each endpoint will have its own queue. If you are just starting your work and want to try things out, you can go for the first solution, so you will have one queue. In time, you can split your endpoints.

Comment: Can you please check my update on the question and tell me some ideas/solutions? I believe that what you said is correct, but I need a correct way of using it so that the service doesn't crash/become useless.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it - I think it should work as expected, will follow-up and let you know soon. Your explanation was really helpful as obviously I wasn't configuring MassTransit as I was supposed to. So, many thanks!

Comment: @user1639822 please consider removing the accepted answer mark because the code there will not deliver the desired result and it will confuse people who will try using this code for their MassTransit configuration.

Comment: Yes, I will do that now. Please check my updated question - I run into an error, and I have no idea why. I am having the correct using statements in place as well, still that error comes. My consumers implement `MassTransit.IConsumer<T>`

Comment: Why are you using Autofac? Clearly, the error comes from the Autofac integration package.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I know nothing about MassTransit - I've never worked with it before and in fact, never even heard about it until reading the question.

You should probably check out [Alexey Zimarev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53084939/3094533) since he suggest a different way to work with MassTransit configuration. (Having no experience with this tool I can't even know if it's better or not, but that is probably something you can check yourself.)

My answer is purely from the C# point of view.

The first thing that pops to mind is to create a method to configure the `ReceiveEndpoint` - something like this (I don't know the types involved, you will probably need to change them):

```
void ConfigureEndPoint<T>(Host host, Config cfg, Provider provider, string endPointName)
{
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, endPointName, e =>
    {
        e.LoadFrom(provider);
        EndpointConvention.Map<T>(e.InputAddress);
    }
}
```

And then, in your lambda expression, you simply use it like this:

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host("xyz", "/", hst =>
    {
        hst.Username("user");
        hst.Password("pass");
    });
    ConfigureEndPoint<Class1>(host, cfg, provider, "some_endp_1");
    ConfigureEndPoint<Class2>(host, cfg, provider, "some_endp_2");
    // ... a lot more of these here ...
    ConfigureEndPoint<Classn>(host, cfg, provider, "some_endp_n");        
}));
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work with MassTransit and the way it sets itself up. Although it is syntactically correct (I adjusted the void ConfigureEndPoint to match types), and it compiles and runs as well.  

However, it crashes on the first attempt to call the API endpoint linked to this.

Comment: At the same time, the original code (which doesn't use another helper method) works perfectly, as expected.

Comment: "it crashes on the first attempt to call the API endpoint linked to this." I've never worked with MassTransit, but perhaps the error message you get when it crashes can help you figure out what's wrong...

Comment: And, for real, do _NOT_ use .LoadFrom() - particularly when multiple receive endpoints are present with a single provider. You're just consuming everything everywhere. Look at Alexey's answer below for the proper syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your input Chris - I know that you have more in-depth knowledge of these things. How should I do this properly then? I checked Alexey's response. I am having multiple consumers connected to the same bus. Each consumer will then also return a response with `.RespondAsync()`, which I then await from the API endpoint to then display a message (for commands) and a result (for queries). I am doing this to keep CQRS principles, as this is a giant project having many services. What is the best practice for the receive endpoints and the overall communication?

Comment: I am not sure why this is the accepted answer since the code to configure the endpoint is just wrong. Endpoint conventions do not configure how messages are delivered to the endpoint, it only tells MassTransit where to send (not publish) a message when `Send(message)` is used, without getting an instance of `ISendEndpoint` first.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev That is something to ask the OP. Personally, I've never worked with MassTransit before and I think posting this answer might have been a mistake, but now I can't delete it because it's the accepted answer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I see your point from the C# language point of view. The original question code was wrong and it went to your answer. I am not blaming you but I just need people to be aware that the code would not do what it is expected to do.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I've added a disclaimer on my answer - that's really all I can do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** My answer assumes there is an overload for `.Map()` that takes a `Type` instead of being `Generic`. (e.g. `.Map(typeof(Class1), e.InputAddress)`) as this is pretty common among such generic functions.

*If this is not the case, then ignore this answer. I feel it could still be useful for someone else in a similar situation that finds this question*.

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host("xyz", "/", hst =>
    {
        hst.Username("user");
        hst.Password("pass");
    });

    var mappingTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2), ... etc };
    foreach (var mappingType in mappingTypes)
    {
        // I did mappingType.Name for simplicity, but you could get the mappingType's index in the collection and use that as well if you need this to be a number.
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "some_endp_" + mappingType.Name, e =>
        {
            e.LoadFrom(provider);
            // See note at the top of answer.
            EndpointConvention.Map(mappingType, e.InputAddress);
        });
    }

}));
```

Comment: `EndpointConvention.Map(mappingType, e.InputAddress)` doesn't work - the non-generic method of the method doesn't take a type as a parameter. That would make things easier :-)